# google maps redraws after clicking back button

Tags: android, redraw

I have a google maps with different markers in my application. When I tap a marker (onTap()), a new detail window appears and theres some information about the specific location. My problem is that when I click back, the whole map redraws. I can see it, because the shadow of the markers is getting darker every time I open an infowindow and click the back button. Furthermore, it always zooms back to my current location (-> triggers the whole onResume() method).

How can I avoid that the map gets redrawn every time?

Overlay item class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    Item item = map.get(item);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, SomeExampleClass.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

    return true;
}
```

Map Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mainmap);
    mapView.invalidate();

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   

    dbZugriff = new DatabaseAccess(this);

    mylocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mc = mapView.getController();

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    mylocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();


    mapView.getOverlays().add(mylocationoverlay);
    mylocationoverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            GeoPoint myLocation = mylocationoverlay.getMyLocation();
            mc.animateTo(myLocation);
            mc.setZoom(16);

            mapView.postInvalidate();
        }

    });

      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      SpecialitiesSelection specialitiesSelection = SpecialitiesSelection.loadFromPreferences(prefs, "");

    Cursor resultat = dbZugriff.createCursor(specialitiesSelection); 

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays(); 

    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

    if (resultat.moveToFirst()){
        do{

        Item daten = Item.createFromCursor(resultat);
        list.add(daten);

        }
        while(resultat.moveToNext());            
    }

Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
itemizedoverlay = new  ItemOverlay(drawable,this,list);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `onResume()` is being called every time you press BACK from SomeExampleClass. In `onResume()`, you are doing everything you say that you do not want to have happen. Hence, move this code someplace else (e.g., `onCreate()`).